# Client side form validity check for 1 element only

Tags: jquery, forms, validation, onchange

I am looking for a way to have a form element be validated immediately after its value changes.

So far I have the following:

```
$('#loanApplicationForm input, select').change(function() {
    var $myForm = $('#loanApplicationForm'); 
    $('<input type="submit">').hide().appendTo($myForm).click().remove();    
    $myForm.find(':submit').click(); 
}
```

Unfortunately this submits the entire form for validity checking.

I also tried this, however it just returns a true/false boolean rather than doing the client side validation:

```
$(this)[0].checkValidity();
```

Comment: Could you also add your form HTML?

Comment: Will it make a difference? The form is quite long with many input fields and stuff, would just clutter the question I feel. If the proposed solutions would work, they would work for any form.

Comment: It would be useful if there was a demo of your problem. That's why I asked about the HTML.

Comment: @evilgenious448 Answer updated. *Press F5 if you don't see all 3 demos.*

Answer (score 0):

A few pointers:

1. cache your form element outside function *(so that the element caching is done once and stored to be reused - otherwise the caching is re-done every time the function is rerun, which is at every keystroke)*
2. use `.keyup()` event to catch each keystroke for validation testing
3. use `$form.submit()` to submit the form - no need to inject a submit button and click it.

```js
$form = $('#myForm');
$('#theInput').keyup(function(){
  if ( this.value == 'yay' ){
    $form.submit();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="myForm" action="endpoint.php" method="submit">
  <input id="theInput" type="text" placeholder="type: yay" />
</form>
```

#### Updated:

Per OP request, correct validation will display a submit button rather than auto-submitting the form.

```js
$form = $('#myForm');
$('#theInput').keyup(function(){
  if ( this.value == 'yay' ){
    $('#btnSubmit').show();
  }
});
```

```css
#btnSubmit{display:none};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="myForm" action="endpoint.php" method="submit">
  <input id="theInput" type="text" placeholder="type: yay" />
  <button id="btnSubmit" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Here is another version that you might prefer - the submit button is always visible, but disabled until the validation is successful. Also, I added a second field for the validation testing in case you need to validate multiple fields in your actual project.

```js
$form = $('#myForm');
$('#myForm input').keyup(function(){
  if ( $('#theInput1').val() == 'yay' && $('#theInput2').val() == 'bob' ){
    $('#btnSubmit').attr('disabled', false).addClass('fgGreen');
  }
});
```

```css
.fgGreen{color:green;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="myForm" action="endpoint.php" method="submit">
  <input id="theInput1" type="text" placeholder="type: yay" />
  <input id="theInput2" type="text" placeholder="type: bob" />
  <button id="btnSubmit" type="submit" disabled>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: The submit button with click is because I don't actually want to submit the form. I think you have misunderstood my question. The point is to just instant validation check for the user to know if they have made a mistake, not to actually submit the form.

Comment: Okay, let me chnage that... hang on must run an errand...

Comment: I will hang on brother.

Comment: Sorry for delay - updated per your request.  I left the previous version there for your reference in case it later becomes useful.